# SSRS 2017 Subscription can't be created or edited because the credentials used to run the report are not stored

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have an ssrs server that is not allowing me to create subscriptions for some reports.  There are 20+ reports in a folder which all use the same data source: /Data Sources/MyDataSource.  The credentials are stored in the data source.  I can add subscriptions to most of the reports, but there are a few which throw the following error:

> **An Error Has Occurred:**
> Subscription can't be created or edited because
> the credentials used to run the report are not stored, or if a linked
> report, the link is no longer valid.

I have tried deleting the report and re-uploading them, deploying the whole bit from the project and adding another data source with the same stored credentials.  However, I still get the same warning triangle on the subscription button.  There are a batch of new reports I have added, some have this issue and others do not.  Restarting the SSRS service did not help.
Any other ideas for troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

Bonkers!  Looks like the issue was a case sensitivity one.  In the project, all of the reports referred to a shared data source. However, sometimes the reference to the shared data source was spelled "mySharedDataSource" instead of "MySharedDataSource"
I found a hint of this in the logs, which complained about the first version of the spelling which did not exist on the report server.  Fixing that and deploying the report corrected the issue and now I can create subscriptions.

Might be a 2017 thing, I have these reports both on a 2016 and 2019 instance and they have not complained.